# C programming: allocation of pointer lost even when done on the contents of a double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, scope, pass-by-reference

So, I have been grappling with this for a while, and after a good deal of late-night hair-pulling I decided to see if you all wanted to take a crack at it.

In summary, I am trying to setup a dynamically allocated struct for use in a program by handing off the allocation code to another function outside of main. I know of two ways of doing this: one, have the function return a pointer to a allocated struct like:

```
typeStruct *someFunction()
```

Or two, pass in a double pointer to the struct, dereference it, and allocate memory on the inner pointer. Like:

```
void someFunction(typeStruct **ptr)
```

I am attempting to do the latter, as I want to use the return value for a char flag rather than the struct itself.

Unfortunately, it seems that changes made on a deference of the pointer don't make it past the scope of the function. I managed to replicate my problem with a simpler sample program. Here is the code:

test.c:

```
#include "testheader.h"

int main() {

    char success = 0;
    test *t;
    printf("\nBefore setup (in Main), Test: %d", t);
    success = setupTest(&t);
    printf("\nAfter setup (in Main), Test: %d", t);

    free(t->numbers);
    free(t);

    return success;
}
```

testheader.c:

```
#include "testheader.h"

const int NUM_NUMBERS = 100;

char setupTest(test **ptr) {
    printf("\nBefore deference, Test: %d", *ptr);
    char flag = 0;
    test *t = *ptr;
    printf("\nBefore malloc, Test: %d", t);
    t = malloc(sizeof(test));
    printf("\nAfter malloc, Test: %d", t);
    if(t != NULL) {
        t->numbers = malloc(sizeof(int) * NUM_NUMBERS);
        if(t->numbers != NULL) {
            for(int i = 0; i < NUM_NUMBERS; ++i) t->numbers[i] = i;
        } else flag = 1;
    } else flag = 1;
    printf("\nEnd of setup, Test: %d", t);
    return flag;
}
```

testheader.h:

```
#ifndef TESTHEADER_H
#define TESTHEADER_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct test_t {

    int *numbers;

} test;

char setupTest(test **);

#endif
```

Here is how I am compiling it: gcc test.c testheader.c -o test.exe

I am using gcc 5.1.0 to compile in git bash and Windows 10's console to run.

Here is my output from running test.exe:
[Console debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMt1j.png)

And then it crashes. As one can see, the inside the function behaves as expected, although the code outside it does not reflect the allocation made inside, as if I had just passed the pointer itself rather than passing by reference with a double pointer.

Is there something I am missing here?

Diagnosis:

The lines

```
test *t = *ptr;
t = malloc(sizeof(test));
```

Only effect the local variable t, and not the contents of **ptr.

Solution:

malloc on the contents of **ptr rather than a local variable so that the allocation doesn't go out of scope upon return. And swap the two lines.

```
*ptr = malloc(sizeof(test));
test *t = *ptr;
```

Comment: `t` is a local variable and you don't pass it back to the caller, so what do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test *t = *ptr;
```

I don't know whether you think this is setting up some sort of persistent *link* between `t` and `ptr` (like a C++ reference), but it's not. It's simply assigning the latter to the former, which is rendered moot when you get to:

```
t = malloc(sizeof(test));
```

where `t` is overwritten.

What you're missing after that point is some form of assignment back to `**ptr`, meaning that it's left with whatever value it had on entry. This is, of course, what you're seeing.

What you *need* to do is take the value of `t` and populate the passed-in variable with it:

```
*ptr = t;
```

---

You can also clean up your function a little, ensuring that it's atomic - either *everything* should be done or *nothing* should be done (especially in terms of memory allocation). Thius includes any changes to the pointer you passed in the address of:

```
int setupTest(test **ptr) {
    // Allocate a test structure. If fail, return indication.

    test *t = malloc(sizeof(test));
    if (t == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Allocate a numbers sub-structure. If fail,
    // free test structure and return indication.

    t->numbers = malloc(sizeof(int) * NUM_NUMBERS);
    if (t->numbers == NULL) {
        free(t);
        return 0;
    }

    // Have both structures, populate and return success.

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_NUMBERS; ++i) {
        t->numbers[i] = i;
    }
    *ptr = t;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Just fixed it. Both the test program and the larger program don't have that bug anymore. I figured it would be something painfully obvious that stemmed from a misuse of pointers. Now I will know to avoid that in the future. I posted the solution in my post. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

you can consider it like this:
because `test *p` => `p = malloc()`
so `test **p` => `*p = malloc()`

it should malloc to *ptr but not ptr.

```
char setupTest(test **ptr) {
    printf("\nBefore deference, Test: %d", *ptr);
    char flag = 0;
    test **t = ptr;
    printf("\nBefore malloc, Test: %d", *t);
    *t = malloc(sizeof(test));
    printf("\nAfter malloc, Test: %d", *t);
    if(t != NULL) {
        (*t)->numbers = malloc(sizeof(int) * NUM_NUMBERS);
        if((*t)->numbers != NULL) {
            for(int i = 0; i < NUM_NUMBERS; ++i) (*t)->numbers[i] = i;
        } else flag = 1;
    } else flag = 1;
    printf("\nEnd of setup, Test: %d", *t);
    return flag;
}
```

Or, direct malloc to `*ptr`

```
char setupTest(test **ptr) {
    printf("\nBefore deference, Test: %d", *ptr);
    char flag = 0;
    printf("\nBefore malloc, Test: %d", *ptr);
    *ptr = malloc(sizeof(test));
    printf("\nAfter malloc, Test: %d", *ptr);
    if(*ptr != NULL) {
        (*ptr)->numbers = malloc(sizeof(int) * NUM_NUMBERS);
        if((*ptr)->numbers != NULL) {
            for(int i = 0; i < NUM_NUMBERS; ++i) (*ptr)->numbers[i] = i;
        } else flag = 1;
    } else flag = 1;
    printf("\nEnd of setup, Test: %d", *ptr);
    return flag;
}
```